# AttributeError: 'model.name' object has no attribute 'generate'

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to call a function from a wizard button but I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'model.name' object has no attribute 'generate'

AttributeError: 'model.name' object has no attribute 'generate'

this is my model code:

```
class wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'model.name'
department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department')
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
date_from = fields.Date(string = 'Start Date', required = True)
date_to = fields.Date(string = 'End Date', required = True)
state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('verify', 'Waiting'),('done', 'Done'),('cancel', 'Rejected'),])
def generate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'draft'}, context=context)
```

In the xml file:

```
<button name ="generate" type="object" string="Generate" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: check the indentation  of def generate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

Comment: problem resolved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indentation issue in your code, fields and methods which are belongs to class must be the next level in indentation.

```
class wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'model.name'

    department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department')
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
    date_from = fields.Date(string = 'Start Date', required = True)
    date_to = fields.Date(string = 'End Date', required = True)
    state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('verify', 'Waiting'),    ('done', 'Done'),('cancel', 'Rejected'),])

    def generate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'draft'}, context=context)
```

Comment: I noticed the indentation problem here. I thought that, in the original code, it was Ok but it seems that it wasn't :/. I copied your code and it's working.Thanks for your time.